# Write Newton binomial in Fortran90

Tags: fortran

I have to write an script in Fortran that returns the results of the Newton binomial:
[for a, b and n given.](http://sauce.pntic.mec.es/~rmarti9/imagenes/binewton.gif)

The problem is that I cant use functions or subroutines.

Until now I have written the code for the combinations:

```
    if (n==0) then
        print*, "Cnk=",Cnk
else if ((n>=0).and.(k==0)) then
        print*, "Cnk=",Cnk
else
        do i=1,n,1
                aux=aux*i

                if (k==i) then
                        factK=aux
                end if

                if ((n-k)==i) then
                        factnk=aux
                end if

                factn=aux
        end do

        Cnk=factn/(factk*factnk)

        print*, "Cnk=",Cnk

end if
```

In the case of the binomial k is variable from 0 to n.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the fastest solution, but quite short:

```
program binom

  implicit none
  integer,parameter :: N=5
  integer,parameter :: a=3
  integer,parameter :: b=5
  integer           :: k, i
  integer           :: coeff, eval, total

  total = 0 
  do i=0,N
    coeff = product((/ (k,k=1,n) /)) / product((/ (k,k=1,i),(k,k=1,n-i) /))
    eval  = coeff * a**(n-i) * b**i
    total = total + eval
    write(*,*) 'i=',i,'coeff=',coeff, 'eval=',eval
 enddo !i
 write(*,*) '(a+b)**n=',(a+b)**N,'Total=',total

end program binom
```

Output:

```
 i=           0 coeff=           1 eval=         243
 i=           1 coeff=           5 eval=        2025
 i=           2 coeff=          10 eval=        6750
 i=           3 coeff=          10 eval=       11250
 i=           4 coeff=           5 eval=        9375
 i=           5 coeff=           1 eval=        3125
 (a+b)**n=       32768 Total=       32768
```